# Animating Particle System in Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using the following code to animate some particles in a particle system in Three.js.

```
for(var i = 0; i < particleSystem.geometry.vertices.length; i++ ){
                        var pX = Math.sin(i + counter) * 100 + Math.random() * 20,
                            pY = Math.cos(i + counter) * 100 + Math.random() * 20,
                            pZ = Math.sin(i + counter) * 100 + Math.random() * 20;
                            particleSystem.geometry.vertices[i] = new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ);
                        }
```

It works by changing the vertices of the particles. It changes them fine with no error, but there is no update. I can move around and all of the other animation is working fine. This is in my `animate()` function, like this:

```
function animate(){


            for(var i = 0; i < particleSystem.geometry.vertices.length; i++ ){
            var pX = Math.sin(i + counter) * 100 + Math.random() * 20,
                pY = Math.cos(i + counter) * 100 + Math.random() * 20,
                pZ = Math.sin(i + counter) * 100 + Math.random() * 20;
                particleSystem.geometry.vertices[i] = new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ);
            }



        counter += 1;


        requestAnimationFrame(animate); // So it stops when you change window and otherwise repeats
    renderer.render(scene,camera); // Render
    controls.update(clock.getDelta()); // Update control/camera movement information

}
```

Comment: you could try https://github.com/Alchemist0823/three.quarks which handles all the particle interactions and has marketplace https://quarks.art/store to download particle systems.

Answer (score 4):

First, I think you should update the vertices, not replacing them by new instances:

```
particleSystem.geometry.vertices[i].set( pX, pY, pZ );
```

Then, you also may have to tell Three.js that the vertices have changed:

```
particleSystem.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

These should be done during the `update()`